# Keras (R) - Why are predicted probabilities (binary classification) the same for all inputs?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, time-series, sliding-window

I use Keras in R to train a fully connected neural network for time series forecasting (binary classification). In order to use a standard multilayer perceptron for this task I transform my time series data using the sliding window approach (add lagged input features to the data). Hence, with 1 binary label, 2 input time series and a lookback of 2 (for illustration) the transformed data has the following structure:

```
    label     a     b     a.1     b.1     a.2     b.2
1    1       0.1   0.3     NA      NA      NA      NA
2    1       0.2   0.2     0.1    0.3      NA      NA
3    0       0.4   0.4     0.2    0.2      0.1    0.3
4    1       0.1   0.6     0.4    0.4      0.2    0.2
5    0       0.15  0.25    0.1    0.6      0.4    0.4
...
```

After omitting the NA rows and removing the a and b columns the data matrix used looks like this:

```
    label    a.1     b.1     a.2     b.2
3    0       0.2     0.2     0.1     0.3
4    1       0.4     0.4     0.2     0.2
5    0       0.1     0.6     0.4     0.4
...
```

In the next steps I create two thresholds for splitting the data in a train, validation and test set and do the actual splitting based on these thresholds:

```
## Thresholds
train_valid_split = 1700
valid_test_split = 1800

## amount of features (columns of data matrix minus first label column)
features = ncol(data_mlp) - 1 

## Container for train, validation and test set (both input x and label y)
train_x = array(0, dim = c(train_valid_split, features))
train_y = array(0, dim = c(train_valid_split))
valid_x = array(0, dim = c((valid_test_split-train_valid_split), features))
valid_y = array(0, dim = c((valid_test_split-train_valid_split)))
test_x = array(0, dim = c((nrow(data_mlp)-valid_test_split), features))
test_y = array(0, dim = c((nrow(data_mlp)-valid_test_split)))

## Fill container with the data
train_x = data_mlp[1:train_valid_split, 2:ncol(data_mlp)]
train_y = data_mlp[1:train_valid_split, 1, drop=F]
valid_x = data_mlp[(train_valid_split+1):valid_test_split, 2:ncol(data_mlp)]
valid_y = data_mlp[(train_valid_split+1):valid_test_split, 1, drop=F]
test_x = data_mlp[(valid_test_split+1):nrow(data_mlp), 2:ncol(data_mlp)]
test_y = data_mlp[(valid_test_split+1):nrow(data_mlp), 1, drop=F]
```

After calculating the amount of validation steps I train and fit the following Keras model:

```
## Validation steps
valid_steps = valid_test_split - train_valid_split

## Keras sequential model
model = keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32, input_shape = c(features),
              activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "adam", # rmsprop
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history = model %>% fit(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  steps_per_epoch = 90,
  epochs = 10,
  validation_data = list(valid_x, valid_y),
  validation_steps = valid_steps,
  shuffle=FALSE
)
```

However, when evaluating the model on the test set by predicting class probabilities for all test inputs, all probabilities are exactly the same. Hence, the same class is predicted for every input.

```
> results = model %>% predict(test_x)
> results
           [,1]
 [1,] 0.5740806
 [2,] 0.5740806
 [3,] 0.5740806
 [4,] 0.5740806
 [5,] 0.5740806
 [6,] 0.5740806
 [7,] 0.5740806
  ...
```

I don't understand why the probabilities are identical. I tried to play around with different input data, different lookback (more or less lags), more epochs, more steps_per_epoch, different optimizer, different amount of units, etc. The predicted probabilities changed but they always were the same for all inputs.

Interestingly, a lstm model on the same data, with the same validation and test splits and the same lookback does not yield the same probabilities. The lstm result is way more reasonable. But I also wanted to try the MLP + sliding window approach since I read it might yield better forecasting performance on certain tasks. So my guess is there is a mistake in my data preperation (sliding window) or model architecture but I cannot figure out what it is...

If you have any suggestions of why the result is as it is and how I could change it, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Best, hokage

PS: If you need more information, let me know what it is and I try my best to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the code, causing the input vector to be only zeros. Now it's fixed and code works properly.